# Rotation of a vector proof

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, rotations

How would I prove that multiplying a vector by two rotation matrices of different angles is equivalent to multiplying the vector by a rotation matrix of the angles added together? I understand how to prove it for two specific angles, but I'm not sure how to generalize it for all angles.

Comment: If you are in 2-D, this is super simple once you have the standard representation of rotation matrices via trig functions.  It just comes out to those sum-of-angles formulas.

Comment: Oh, and it's false for 3-D and higher because you can have different axes of rotation, which can't happen in the plane.  (Assuming all are linear maps fixing 0.)

Comment: Ah. Thanks so much! I had worked it out, but I hit a point where I couldn't simplify anymore. I just needed to use the sum-of-angles formulas.

Comment: Could it have something to do with a+b=c. Or maybe matrix multiplication, of course taking into consideration the R^3 deal. That would be done if you assumed this is in R^2.

Comment: When I was a TA for linear algebra courses I actually liked to give an example which was this argument in reverse to prove the sum-of-angle formulas - first, rotation is linear by a geometric argument (e.g. a parallelogram rotates to a parallelogram), and then it's easy to see what that rotation does to the basis vectors.

Comment: my best bet would be matrix multiplication, use angle theta and angle phi, with a 2 by 2 matrix, do them individually, then do them as one, they should be identical or equivalent

Answer (score 0):

Note that in the 2d-plane rotations are equivalent to multiplication by a complex on the unit circle.

$z=x+iy\longleftrightarrow \vec u=(x,y)^T$

$ze^{i\theta}=(x+iy)(\cos\theta+i\sin \theta)=(x\cos\theta-y\sin\theta)+i(x\sin\theta+y\cos\theta)$

$R(\theta).\vec u=\begin{bmatrix}\cos\theta & -\sin\theta\\\sin\theta & \cos\theta\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}x\cos\theta -y\sin\theta\\ x\sin\theta+y\cos\theta\end{bmatrix}$

So $\quad z\,e^{i\theta}\longleftrightarrow R(\theta).\vec u$

Now it is straightforward that chaining rotations is adding angles since $z\,e^{i\theta_1}\,e^{i\theta_2}=z\,e^{i(\theta_1+\theta_2)}$